Iframe keeps has scroll inside body
I have an Iframe inside a modal. I can't set a fix height to the Iframe because the different pages inside it have different heights. If I set height to 100%, my iframe is 150px height and I have scroll in it.
How can I set the height so there is no scroll and the scroll is handle by the NextUI modal with scrollBehaviour:outside?
Iframe component:
const IframeComponent = () => {
  return <iframe title="wheel" url="XXXX" className="h-full w-full rounded-[30px]" />
}

export default IframeComponent

Modal component:
import { Modal, ModalBody, ModalContent, ModalProps, useDisclosure } from "@nextui-org/react"
import Image from "next/image"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import IframeComponent from "./Iframe"

const IframeWrapper = () => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure()
  const [scrollBehavior, _setScrollBehavior] = useState<ModalProps["scrollBehavior"]>("outside")

  // Open the modal on load.
  // Does the modal need to open on each load?
  useEffect(() => {
    onOpen()
  }, [onOpen])

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
        size="5xl"
        placement="center"
        hideCloseButton={true}
        radius="lg"
        scrollBehavior={scrollBehavior}
        className="w-[90vw]"
      >
        <ModalContent>
          <>
            <ModalBody className="p-0">
              <button
                onClick={onClose}
                className="absolute right-4 top-3 select-none appearance-none rounded-full p-2 text-foreground-500 outline-none tap-highlight-transparent data-[focus-visible=true]:z-10 data-[focus-visible=true]:outline-2 data-[focus-visible=true]:outline-offset-2 data-[focus-visible=true]:outline-focus rtl:left-1 rtl:right-[unset] lg:right-10 lg:top-7"
              >
                <Image
                  src="/icons/closeModal.svg"
                  alt="close button"
                  width={0}
                  height={0}
                  className="h-8 w-8 lg:h-16 lg:w-16"
                />
              </button>
              <IframeComponent />
            </ModalBody>
          </>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
export default IframeWrapper


Not sure I understand you right, have you tried setting the scrolling attribute?

Sorry for my explications. I thought that the scrolling attribute was deprecated. It actually works, but how can I set the height so I get the full content without setting a fixed value? As the height can change

You mean setting the height of the iframe based on the height of the embedded page? I don't think you can do it with HTML only. You'll need the help from the server side.

Making an iframe match the size of the content is an unnecessarily complex task even in modern browsers. It’s actually three different problems.
Reliable calculate the size of the content, the browser provides half a dozen ways of doing this that all give different answers and none of which is consistently correct. If the content doesn’t over flow the body element then document.body.getClientRect().bottom will likely give the best answer.
The next problem is detecting the content of the page has changed, so you know to remeasure the content size. The ResizeObserver API is helpful for this and will detect most things, so long as everything is inside the body element of your page. If not then it gets more complex and you likely need to start using the MutationObserver API as well.
Finally you then have to pass the new height from the iframe to the parent page. This is where the PostMessage API comes to the rescue.
If this all sounds a bit more work than you where expecting, then I wrapped all together in a JS library called iframe-resizer. There is even a React component for it.

It looks pretty interesting. But for that I need to add a part inside the iframe itself, so I need to have access to its code, right?

Yep, it is impossible to achieve this without access to the iframe.

Ok, thank you. I'll keep that way in mind
